# how can we set textbox value to dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 function SetUtcTimeZone() {
     var UTCTimeZone = document.getElementById("txtPortorAnchorDeparture").value;
     document.getElementById('ddlUTCTimeZone').selectedIndex = UTCTimeZone;
 }
```

---

how can we set textbox value to dropdownlist using dropdownlist id

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would look like this:

```
function SetTxt() {
     var indx = document.getElementById('ddlUTCTimeZone').selectedIndex;
     var val  = document.getElementById('ddlUTCTimeZone').options[indx].text;
     document.getElementById("txtPortorAnchorDeparture").value = val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `.selectedIndex` by `.value` it will be done
**Try this**

```js
function SetUtcTimeZone() {
  var UTCTimeZone = document.getElementById("txtPortorAnchorDeparture").value;
  document.getElementById('ddlUTCTimeZone').value = UTCTimeZone;
}
```

```html
<!-- Simple example -->
<select id="ddlUTCTimeZone">
  <option value="1">USA</option>
  <option value="2">Egypt</option>
  <option value="0">GMT</option>
</select>
<input id="txtPortorAnchorDeparture" type="text" />
<button type="button" onclick="SetUtcTimeZone()">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function

```
function dropdownToTextbox(dropdown, textbox) {
    var selectedOption = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex];
    textbox.value = selectedOption.value;
}
```